# Why `trait T; class C; class X extends (C with T)` can't be compiled?

Tags: scala, type-systems

Scala code:

```
trait T
class C
type W = C with T
class X extends W
```

`W` is a type alias, but I want define a class to extend it. Why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have difficulty structuring my answer in a nice way, but here is nevertheless an attempt at explaining what's going on:

You get a compilation error because the `extends` clause requires class and traits, not types, and you're giving a type. Classes and traits must not be confused with types.

There are certainly better explanations of this out there. But basically a type specifies the operations that can be applied to something (and sometimes other properties). Classes and traits define the *behavior* of their instances.

In most statically typed OO languages, every class/interface/trait also has an associated *type*. However, the reciprocal is typically not true: not all types have a corresponding class/interface/trait. For example, your `C with T` is a type, but not a class nor a trait (nor even a combination thereof).

The `extends` clauses expects classes and traits (separated by `with`), but not one type. This is because `extends` means: extend the *behavior* of this thing. As I said, types do not define behavior.

In most places, the syntax `A with B` represents a *type* which is a subtype of both the type `A` and the type `B`. In the `extends` clause, however, `with` takes a different meaning, and simply acts as a separator for the arguments of `extends` (much like `,` acts as separator for arguments to a method call).

If you write `class X extends C with T`, it will work, because it means `class X extends C, T`, if you want.

HTH

Comment: "You get a compilation because the extends clause requires class and traits, not types" suffices, delete the rest :)

Answer (score 1):

String is a final class, cannot be extended.

Comment: Although this is correct, the problem is that type extension is not supported, even if instead of string you use some custom class, it still won't compile.

Comment: Right, I changed it to a custom class, same compilation error