# Anonymous subclass of a parametric type by the use of ClassTag context bound

Tags: scala

Given a concrete class of a given trait

```
trait Trt {
    val x: Int
}

class C extends Trt {
    val x: Int = 3
}
```

I'd like to create an object of an anonymous class of a parametric type in order to override the attribute `x`

```
abstract class SomeClass[T <: Trt : ClassTag] {
   def f: Unit = {
      val original = new C

      //Is this even possible?
      val withOverridenX = new T { override val x = 42}

      assert(original.x != withOverridenX.x)
   }
}
```

The problem is that the compiler keeps reporting the following error:

```
>> Error:(26, 35) class type required but T found
```

Is instancing anonymous classes extenging parametric types classes even possible?

I know the problem is that `T` is a type and not a class and I wonder if maybe, thanks to ClassTag bounded contex, it could be possible to instantiate `withOverridenX`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why \`trait T; class C; class X extends (C with T)\` can't be compiled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960083/why-trait-t-class-c-class-x-extends-c-with-t-cant-be-compiled)

Comment: @sjrd  Is there any way to, for example using ClassTag, be able to instantiate an anonymous class of a parametric type (yes I know it is a type)  providing the class information at runtime and, somehow, using it?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that, even with a `ClassTag`. You would need a `TypeTag` and compile-time reflection (macros) to do this, I guess (I don't exactly know how).

Comment: Thanks for your comments and congratulations for Scala.js, it helped me a lot to illustrate some uses of Scala for mi blog: (just the examples, not the blog)
http://orionsword.no-ip.org/demos/pi_scalajs/
http://orionsword.no-ip.org/demos/sierpinski_publish/

Comment: @sjrd Just for the record, I found a dirty workaround using Scala's reflection (auto-answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't instantiate `T` since it is not known at runtime, just at compile time. The `ClassTag` would just give you acces to the `Class` object of `T` through the `runtimeClass` method. But with just that, you can't subclass `T` by calling `new`, since there's for example no evidence that `T` has a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Yes but that is why I am trying to use the evidence of `ClassTag` given by the context bound.

Comment: I elaborated a little bit mor, see above.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround which allows to do exactly as I want which is: Get an instance of `C` (or a subclass of `C`) with a different value for `x` than the one given at its declaration time.

Whenever someone wants to abuse a programming language it is usual to turn to reflection. Since version 2.10, Scala offers [its own reflection](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) capabilities (aside Java's) so it is possible to change `x` for `withOverridenX`:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

abstract class SomeClass[T <: Trt : TypeTag ] {
   def f: Unit = {
      val original = new C
      val withOverridenX = new C

      //This gets the term representation for the attribute 'x'...
      val xTerm = typeOf[T].declaration(newTermName("x")).asTerm

      //... which can be used to reflect the attribute:
      val m = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
      val reflectedC = m.reflect(withOverridenX)
      val reflectedX = reflectedC.reflectField(xTerm)

      reflectedX.set(42)

      assert(original.x != withOverridenX.x)
   }
}
```